# Wrong group coloring for R barplot

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to create a barplot using R, but the group coloring in the legend looks wrong.

[image]

```
data = c(29,5,22,12,20,11,14,15,21,8)

colors = c(gray.colors(1, start = .1),gray.colors(1, start = .1),
           gray.colors(1, start = .3),gray.colors(1, start = .3),
           gray.colors(1, start = .5),gray.colors(1, start = .5),
           gray.colors(1, start = .7),gray.colors(1, start = .7),
           gray.colors(1, start = .9),gray.colors(1, start = .9))

names = c('1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4','5','5')

barplot(rev(data), horiz=TRUE, col = rev(colors), names.arg = rev(names),
        legend.text = rev(c("1","2","3","4","5")), las=1, xlim = c(0,30), 
        args.legend = list(x ='bottomright', inset=c(0,0.05))
)
```

I can imagine what's  causing this. My initial guess is that I should've used a matrix instead of a vector and then set `beside = True`, but when I do this the bars aren't evenly spaced.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but your legend has too few colors. If you double the length of the vector, `legend.text = rev(rep(c("1","2","3","4","5"), each = 2))`, it doesn't seem wrong anymore. But then the legend is not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `fill` option of legend.

```
barplot(rev(data), horiz=TRUE, col = rev(colors), 
        names.arg = rev(names),
        legend.text = rev(c("1","2","3","4","5")), 
        las=1, xlim = c(0,30), 
        args.legend = list(x ='bottomright', inset=c(0,0.05), 
                           fill=unique(colors))
)
```